# SQL query update in jdbc reciver

Tags: sap-pi

What query need to be given in update SQL query field in JDBC sender filed insted of  to stop repeating file process.i have tried executing the jdbc to file senario in sap pi it's continuously triggering the same data want to stop that and should read only till null value comes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to identify a field to mark the item you already read.

Let's say the field is `STATUS` for example with valid fields

- blank -> the item has not been read before
- 'X' -> the item has already been read and must not be processed again

Select new items in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE STATUS = ''
```

Update read items with

```
UPDATE TABLE SET STATUS = 'X' WHERE STATUS = ''
```

Note that the two statements MUST have exactly the same WHERE condition

For further reference please refer to [Configuring the Sender JDBC Adapter](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw75/7.5.5/en-US/22/b4d13b633f7748b4d34f3191529946/frameset.htm)